# Automated file transfer software for Windows

Tags: windows, backup

I am looking for a recommendation for software that automatically moves files from drive A to B.

When Drive A is nearly full oldest files should be moved to drive B and when Drive B is nearly full oldest files should be deleted. Moving and deletion should only be based on how full the drive is not how old or how big the files are and the software should warn and prevent the OS from restarting or shutting down (due to update or user input) while transfer is happening.

Is there any software that can handle this kind of process automatically on window. I can't run any other OS than Windows, so that is vital.

Comment: I would say something like [iPerius](http://www.iperius.com) with a batch script at start/end. Or maybe even Cobian.

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName That link does not run

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Microsoft flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/nl-nl/) account.

After that you have to link your google drive account with flow.
Then you have to add a condition that whenever a new file is added to the drive: check the available space in the drive, and if it's above a certain percentage move the file to the other designated drive.
For the second drive you apply the same condition but the action would be to delete the files.

This whole thing will happen in the cloud so you do not need to have your system switched on.

Comment: As you describe it, this moves the new file. That is not what the OP wants: *oldest files should be moved*. (S)He also does not want a cloud solution.